# Create Facebook login button in a Flash website

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

I want to integrate the facebook login button into my website. A user can log in using his/her facebook account only. I'm not interested in any other information about the user.

But I'm a little confused... I read the official facebook documentation, and I did not understand what i need. I'm undecided if I need to use the **[Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)** or the **[Login-Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/)** of the **Social Plugin**

Can you please help me solve my doubts?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To use this in flash, you have to use the javascript sdk through some ExternalInterface calls. This is how I always do it.

AS3

```
        public function FBconnect():void {
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("onLogin", onLogin);
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("onError", onError);
            ExternalInterface.call("requestLogin");
        }

        private function onError():void {
            dispatchEvent(new DataEvent(DataEvent.ERROR));
        }

        public function logout():void {
            ExternalInterface.call("FB.logout", null);
        }

        private function onLogin():void {
            debugTools.trace("FB LOGIN");
            connectUser();
        }

        private function connectUser():void {
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("loadUser", userCallback);
            ExternalInterface.call("connectUser");
        }

        private function userCallback(data:Array):void {
            debugTools.trace("FB USER LOADED");
            var userData:Object = data[0];

            _FBuser = new FBUser(userData.id);
            _FBuser.firstName = userData.first_name;
            _FBuser.lastName = userData.last_name;
            _FBuser.email = userData.email;

            dispatchEvent(new DataEvent(DataEvent.SUCCESS));
        }
```

JS

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId: YOUR_APP_ID,
                    status: false,
                    cookie: true,
                    xfbml: false
                });         
            };
            (function() {
              var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
              e.src = document.location.protocol +
                '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
              document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());

            function connectUser() {
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    if(response) {                  
                        var usrs = new Array();
                        usrs.push(response);
                        document.getElementById('flashObj').loadUser(usrs);
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('flashObj').onError();
                    }
                });
            };

            function requestLogin() {
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        document.getElementById('flashObj').onLogin();              
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('flashObj').onError();
                    }
                }, {scope:'email'});
            }
```

So to break it down.

We load in the javascript sdk in our webpage, check the docs on facebook on how to do itn if you don't know.

Next, through the ExternalInterface, we call FB.login in the JS and on response we call an AS3 function through document.getElementById (to access your swf).

Then we do the same thing to use the Graph API to get the info on our user.

In my experience, this is the best workflow to facebook connect your user to your flash Application.

Comment: Uhm, thanks.. Then your council is to create an app, don't to use the social plug-in right?

And What about this method?
http://permadi.com/blog/2011/02/using-facebook-graph-api-in-flash-as3-1-5/comment-page-1/#comment-1752

it's similiar to yours but use the official FB Api

Comment: It's not similar, because it uses an unofficial API. Facebook doesn't have an as3 api (at least not anymore). That API might work, but I don't think it's actively developed anymore, and since Facebook API changes a lot, your best bet IMHO is to stick with this approach, but feel free to use whatever works for you ;)

Comment: And you can't use a social plugin in a flash app, because social plugins are solely for html/css/js. You can't use them in a flash application. You could use them outside your swf and then transfer the data to your swf, but that's not optimal.